# synchronous behavior of System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

As per MSDN blog
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

> The timer events raised by this timer class are synchronous with
>   respect to the rest of the code in your Windows Forms app.any code
>   that resides inside a timer event handler (for this type of timer
>   class) is executed using the application's UI thread

Now take a look on below code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
         timer1.Start();
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
      }

 void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + 1).ToString();
     }
```

My question is

why textBox1 value is being updated while the main UI thread was sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't.  The `Tick` event will still be raised at the appropriate time and the event handler queued.  When the `Sleep` call returns and your `load` event handler completes, then the `Tick` event handler will be executed and the `TextBox` updated.

Note that, if the `Tick` event is raised multiple times while the UI thread is busy/sleeping then the event handler will be executed multiple times once it's free.

To prove it to yourself, try this code:

```
private readonly Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Interval = 15000;
    this.timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    this.timer1.Start();
    this.watch.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Stop();
    this.label1.Text = this.watch.Elapsed.ToString();
}
```

If the `Tick` event handler was updating the `Label` while the UI thread was sleeping then you'd expect the `Text` of the `Label` to represent approximately 15 seconds because that's how long the `Interval` of the `Timer` is.  What you'll see instead is that it represents about 20 seconds, which is how long the UI thread was sleeping.  That shows that the `Tick` event handler wasn't executed until the `Sleep` call had completed.